# G++ error with -lxnt flag after xlnt is installed

Tags: c++, ld

I am trying to install the xlnt library on Ubuntu 18. I have installed xlnt exactly as the [instructions](https://github.com/tfussell/xlnt/blob/master/docs/introduction/Installation.md) say on the repo. When I try to compile my code, the following error pops up:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lxlnt
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
makefile:204: recipe for target 'BOF-debug-static' failed
make: *** [BOF-debug-static] Error 1
```

I have been installing other libraries to get the code working, and I've noticed that the other libraries are creating .a files at /usr/local/lib along with a few other .la, and .so files. When I install xlnt, it is not creating any .a files, but does create a .so and .so.1.2 files. Not sure if that is relevant, but it's something I've noticed.

How do I make xlnt discoverable to g++ and get the -lxlnt flag to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The target you are building `BOF-debug-static` is evidently one that requests 
either a fully static linkage, with the `-static` linkage option, or possibly one that
requests static linkage specifically of `libxlnt`, with a linkage option such as:

```
-Wl,-Bstatic -lxlnt -Wl,-Bdynamic
```

Since, as you observed, `libxlnt` by default provides only a shared/dynamic library `libzlint.so` ( -> `libzlint.so.X.Y.Z)`,
and no static library `libzlnt.a`, the linker ignores the the shared library when
required to link `-lxlnt` statically and says:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lxlnt
```

You cannot link a shared library statically.

However, if you configure the CMake build system with:

```
cmake -DSTATIC=ON [your previous options...]
```

then `make` will build a static library and running `make install` (as root) will create `/usr/local/lib/libxlnt.a`.